# Return value in BASH error

Tags: bash, parameters

I have this little script in bash and i have a weird error :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function fun1(){
  message = "coucou"
  echo $message
}

function fun2(){
  local res=$(fun1)
  echo $res
}

fun1
fun2
```

The output is :

```
./test.sh ligne 4: message: command not found
```

Seem this ligne is a problem but don't know why ...

```
message = "coucou"
```

Comment: Remove spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spaces in your assignment:

```
  message = "coucou"
```

So it treats `message` as a command and `=` and `"coucou"` as arguments to it. Hence, the error.
change it to:

```
  message="coucou"
```